# « Il est tombé 20 cm de la neige. » Pourquoi c’est « être » ?

Tags: grammaire, sens, usage

> Il est tombé *20 cm de la neige.*

Je pense qu’il est un objet donc on doit l’employer avec avoir, n’est-ce pas?

Donc ça serait « il a tombé 20 cm de la neige » (mais ce n’est pas correct).

Pourriez-vous m’expliquer s’il vous plaît?

Merci.

Comment: La phrase correcte est "Il est tombé 20 cm de neige"

Comment: ou: *Il est tombé de la neige, 20 cm.*

Comment: On dit aussi *je suis tombé*, *je suis monté*, *je suis allé*. Il semblerait que le mouvement implique l'emploi de l'auxiliaire *être* et non de *avoir*. Je ne me rappelle plus la règle exacte

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*20 cm de la neige* ne peut pas être un objet : le verbe [*tomber*](https://cnrtl.fr/definition/tomber) est généralement intransitif. Au contraire, *il* est ici un pronom impersonnel. [Le Bescherelle](https://books.google.com/books?id=iRe9DwAAQBAJ&lpg=PT232&ots=mteGUhqOAu&dq=il%20impersonnel%20temps%20tomber%20la%20neige&pg=PT232#v=onepage&q&f=false) donne en fait l'exemple de *il est tombé cette nuit cinquante centimètres de neige* dans sa discussion des constructions impersonnelles.

> - Les constructions impersonnelles associent le sujet impersonnel *il* à un verbe qui connaît par ailleurs des emplois personnels. […]
> - Une construction impersonnelle résulte toujours d'une transformation. […] Une telle transformation est impossible avec les verbes impersonnels.

Comment: C’est parce qu’il y a “de” aussi? Donc c’est un complément pas COD.

Comment: @user16887 Je croire que le _de_ est ici juste une préposition qui attache _la neige_ à _20 centimètres_.